# way to dynamicly create object from JSON format in c# dotnet core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

How can I use JSON to create dynamic object in dotnet core? It used to work in old ASP.NET but in dotnet core it's not.
I use the following code:

```
var json= "{\"itemName\":\"itemValue\"}";
var obj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

I already using Newtonsoft.Json;

If I create a type it works

```
obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<someType>(json);
```

I tried as suggested still doesn't work:

[attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbHsL.png)

Comment: the `var` is what is causing your problem. You can use `dynamic` ie `dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);`

Comment: it doesn't work. 
These shows in object inspection: childrenToken, count, first, hasValue, Last, Next

Answer (score 0):

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json)`